# How to splite datatable into list using c#.net

Tags: c#, list, datatable, copy

I have a very large datatable with columns named ID,Date
there is 12000 records in it.so sample of records is :

```
1001,02/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1002,01/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1001,03/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1004,03/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1005,04/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1001,01/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1004,02/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1006,06/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1005,05/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1002,07/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1003,08/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1001,02/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1004,01/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1005,04/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1002,03/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1003,02/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1006,06/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1004,02/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1005,02/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1002,02/06/2016 12:21:20monday
```

so I want to make a list with below structure

```
 List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> dicc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>>();
```

first item contains ID filed and second item is string array which contains Date fields like below

```
1001
     02/06/2016 12:21:20monday
     01/06/2016 12:21:20monday
     03/06/2016 12:21:20monday
     03/06/2016 12:21:20monday
     04/06/2016 12:21:20monday
     01/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1002
    02/06/2016 12:21:20monday
    06/06/2016 12:21:20monday
    05/06/2016 12:21:20monday
    07/06/2016 12:21:20monday
    08/06/2016 12:21:20monday
1003 
   02/06/2016 12:21:20monday
   01/06/2016 12:21:20monday
   04/06/2016 12:21:20monday
   03/06/2016 12:21:20monday
   02/06/2016 12:21:20monday
```

So how can I do this .please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use a LINQ query to select the `KeyValuePairs` of the `DataTable` like

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> dicc = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(Row => Row["ID"]).Distinct()
    .Select(Id => new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>(
        Id.ToString(),
        dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(Row => Row["ID"].ToString() == Id.ToString())
            //.OrderBy(Row => Row["Date"])
            .Select(Row => Row["Date"].ToString())
            .ToArray()))
    .ToList();
```

Running the query with a `DataTable` like

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID"));
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date"));
dataTable.Rows.Add(1, "Date1");
dataTable.Rows.Add(1, "Date2");
dataTable.Rows.Add(1, "Date3");
dataTable.Rows.Add(2, "Date4");
dataTable.Rows.Add(2, "Date5");
```

returns a list

> 1. **Key:** "1" **Values:** "Date1", "Date2", "Date3"
> 2. **Key:** "2" **Values:** "Date4", "Date5"

Comment: dear Fruchtzwerg
 I want to make a list like exmple how can i do this

Comment: I've updated the query - should now do what you need - check it out :-)

Comment: dear Fruchtzwerg I checked your code but there is no item in string [] array. please trll me why???

Comment: Check if the name of the columns are correct - the code should work (see my example)

Comment: case sensitive? What are the datatypes of your columns?

Comment: Date is datetime but I changed it to string and ID is int

Comment: Ok this was a good hint - the behaviour is caused by a reference comparison - check out the updated query.

Comment: You can add .OrderBy(Row => Row["Date"]) between the where and the select clause.